# Receiving an email upon receiving a message on Facebook

Tags: email, facebook

Since I haven't found yet a way to [set up an auto-responder for Facebook messages](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3098/903)
, and there seems to be no way to [turn on notifications on Facebook for messages only](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66329/18147) I am looking for a browser extension (ideally Chrome), web service or program (ideally supporting Windows 7) that can send me an email when someone send me a message on Facebook. Free is better.